# Google Sheets script to clear checkboxes across multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with 16 tabs. Each tab is the same format. All tabs have checkboxes in column A.

I am attempting to create a button that will clear ALL checkboxes on every tab.

I created a button and assigned this script...

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange('A3:A');
var values = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
    if (values[i][j] == true) {
      values[i][j] = false; // Modified
    }
  }
}
dataRange.setValues(values);
}
```

It clears the checkboxes only on the tab that the button exists on.

How do I modify this script to clear checkboxes across ALL tabs with one click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never done any google sheets scripting but I see this function getSheets() that might be useful? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets()

Could try iterating through all the sheets that way, something like:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var dataRange = sheets[i].getRange('A3:A');
    var values = dataRange.getValues();
    for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
      for (var k = 0; k < values[j].length; k++) {
        values[j][k] = false;
      }
    }
    dataRange.setValues(values);
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried that but I get this error - 

TypeError: Cannot find function getSheets in object Sheet.

When I try to run the script

Comment: Whoops, looks like its SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();